# unable to see the service after stop and starting a service with spring cloud gateway HOXTON.SR5

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I am using spring cloud gateway Hoxton.SR5 version. the thing is when I stop a a service and refresh it again and post the actuator/gateway/refresh, I am not able to find the see the service again. if I downgrade spring-cloud-gateway-core 2.2.0 from 2.2.3 (which Hoxton.SR5) is using, it works properly.

Do you know what is changed or what effected for that issue ?

By the way, it works fine with the old version called Hoxton.RELEASE.It does not work with Hoxton.SR5 version.

Thank you

Pom.xml

```
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Hoxton.SR5</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-gateway-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: FOr starters remove the `version` from the dependencies as those are managed by the imported dependencies section. You are now mixing versions which is somthing you should never be doing (as that will lead to weird incompatible classes exceptions).

Comment: For starters is an expression, but alas. I only pointed out that mixing versions of different jars from a framework is never a good idea (as you now have part things from 2.2.0 and 2.2.3 and potentially also conflicting/unmatched Spring Boot and who knows what other library versions, which eventually will lead to a path of weird(er) issues than the once you have now. But alas apparently one is not allowed to clarify that (also maybe you should check my other answers before you start attacking me about my ego)...

Comment: the problem still persists with the Hoxton.SR5 as I am supposed to use the newest version. What is your advice about the issue ? By the way it is working with Hoxton.RELEASE

Comment: Downgrading parts of a library is never a good idea. Enable debug (or trace) logging and see what happens. Make sure that the services use a compatible version for registering themselves with the gateway.

Comment: by the way during debugging , when I refresh it I can see the newly started the service. but when I run the application with run instead of debug and hits the refresh button I am not able to see the newly created service . routing does not work in run mode at SR5 version

Comment: Now that is weird. Also while debugging you mean putting a breakpoint in place and wait or by just enabling debug logging?

Comment: hello @M.Deinum. yes I meant that putting a breakpoint in place and wait a while. I think this is a bug of Spring Cloud Gateway but I do not know how they fixed it

Comment: I doubt that it is a bug because it works while debugging, I suspect it takes a while for a service to re-register, due to debugging the resolution takes longer and gives the service the time to register. Without debugging it doesn't. Try to run the application with debug logging (i.e start with `--debug`) to get more information on what is happening. You might first want to do that with the old version (RELEASE) then again with the upgrade (SR5) and see what is different.

Comment: Can you provide your configuration? and precise steps to reproduce the issue?